# How do I use rowspan to cover 1.5 times the cell?

Tags: html

This code does not make the last 2 cells cover the 3 three rows.
How should I fix it?
Here's the code:

```html
        <table border="2">
   <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
    <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
   </tr>
   <tr><th>Begin</th><th>End</th></tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>Introduction to XML</td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>Validity:DTD and Relax NG</td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
    <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan="1.5">XPath</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>11 a.m.</td>
    <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td rowspan="1.5">XSL Transformations</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

The rowspan doesn't allow 1.5. How can I do it without doubling all the rows and columns?

Comment: I guess you can't. Setting a different width for that row would solve the problem? Otherwise, I guess you need to split in more rows.

Comment: What do you mean by “the last 2 cells cover the 3 three rows”? There is no concept of half a row in HTML, so you should describe the problem in terms of desired result, not with made-up attribute values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried this example and here is my version:

```
<table width="500px" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2px" style="text-align: center;">
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">DAY</td>
  <td colspan="3">SEMINAR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">SHEDULE</td>
  <td rowspan="2">TOPIC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BEGIN</td>
  <td>END</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
  <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
  <td rowspan="2">5:00 am</td>
  <td>Introduction to xml</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Validaty: DTD and Relax NG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="5">Tuesday</td>
  <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
  <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
  <td rowspan="3">XPath</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
  <td rowspan="2">2:00 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">XSL transformations</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2:00 pm</td>
  <td>5:00 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Wensday</td>
  <td>8:00 am</td>
  <td>12:00 pm</td>
  <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
</tr>
```

Preview [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8p9ewr7f/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's way too late now, but this may just help anyone who faces the same issue in the future.

I used a `rowspan` of "3" and solved the problem using the `<hr>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>5.png</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border: 1px solid;
            }
            th, td {
                border: 1px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <caption></caption>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="3">Day</th>
                <th scope="colgroup" colspan="4">Seminar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="colgroup" colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2" colspan="2">Topic</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Begin</th>
                <th scope="col">End</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>Introduction to XML</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
                <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    <p>XPath
                    <hr>
                    XSL Transformations</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
                <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this example and here is my version:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.inner-table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.inner-table td {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
    <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Begin</th>
    <th>End</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5:00 pm</td>
    <td>Inroduction to Xml</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
    <td>8:00 am</td>
    <td>11:00 a.m</td>
    <td rowspan="3">
     <table class="inner-table">
        <tr>
          <td>XPatx</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XSl Transformation</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12:00 am</td>
    <td>2:00 pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>4:00 pm</td>
    <td>5:00 am</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>8:00 pm</td>
    <td>4:00 am</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objakts</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. My first thinking is double all the rowspan, 1 to 2, 1.5 to 3, etc...

However, it didn't work, I guess it's because empty tr is not rendered. So I place a empty td inside empty tr, and give it a minimum height.

Here is my working example:

html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="5">A</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">B</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">C</td>
    <td class="spaceholder"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td class="spaceholder"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="2">B</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">C</td>
    <td class="spaceholder"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="spaceholder"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="2">B</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">C</td>
   <td class="spaceholder"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="spaceholder"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.spaceholder {
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding:0px;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/luojieemily/pen/oNyKVPY?continueFlag=bfcf85b05f24be30399a7258bfd4977b)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33427658)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table2homwork</title>
    <style>
        table,th,td,tr{
            border:1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
            <th colspan="5">Seminar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
            <th rowspan="2" colspan="3">Topic</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Begin</th>
            <th>End</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
            <td colspan="3">Introduction to XML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Validity:DTD and Relax NG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="3">
                <p>
                    XPath
                    <hr/>
                    XSL Transformations
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <!-- <td rowspan="1.5" colspan="3">XSL Transformations</td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td colspan="3">XSL Formatting Ojects</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with diffrent solution which resembles the problem and also without using css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            #abc {
                height: 75%;
            }
            #def {
                height: 150%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="10">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">schedule</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">topic</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>begin</th>
                    <th>end</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">8:00am</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">5:00pm</td>
                    <td>Introduction to xml</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Validity:DTD & Relax</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
                    <td>8:00am</td>
                    <td>11:00am</td>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        Xpath <br />==================<br />
                        XSL Transformations
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11:00am</td>
                    <td>2:00pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2:00pm</td>
                    <td>5:00pm</td>
                    <!-- <td id="def" rowspan=""></td> -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wednesday</td>
                    <td>8:00am</td>
                    <td>12:00pm</td>
                    <td>XSL Formating Objects</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
        <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Begin</th>
        <th>End</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>Introduction to XML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Validity:DTD and Relax NG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Monday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="1.5">XPath</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="1.5">XSL Transformations</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! It is always best to include text describing what changes you make to code, add references, etc.  In addition to making your answer clearer, this also just draws the eyes of the questioner. i.e. your answer will have better chances of being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need to nest a table inside your table. Be sure to wrap your text inside a `p` tag to expand the border of the inner table to the outer table. Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Schedule Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
        <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Begin</th>
        <th>End</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
        <td rowspan="2">8:00 a. m.</td>
        <td rowspan="2">5:00 p. m.</td>
        <td>Introduction to XML</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
        <td rowspan="1">8:00 a. m.</td>
        <td rowspan="1">11:00 a. m.</td>
        <td rowspan="3">
          <table border="1px" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>XPath</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>XSL Transformation</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">11:00 a. m.</td>
        <td rowspan="1">2:00 p. m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">2:00 p. m.</td>
        <td rowspan="1">5:00 p. m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>8:00 a. m.</td>
        <td>12:00 p. m.</td>
        <td>XSL Formattin Objects</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Begin</th>
                <th>End</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>Introduction to XML</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="5">Tuesday</td>
                <td rowspan="1">8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="1">11:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="3"> XPath </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">11:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="3" >2:00 p.m.</td>
                <td style="border: none;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border: none;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">XSL Transformations</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table border="1px solid #00ff">
          <tr>
            <th rowSpan="3">day</th>
            <th colSpan="3">Seminar</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="2">Schedule</td>
            <td rowSpan="2">Topic</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Begin</td>
            <td>End</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowSpan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowSpan="2">8</td>
            <td rowSpan="2">5</td>
            <td>Intro to XML</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Validity DTD</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowSpan={4}>Tuesday</td>
            <td>8 a.m.</td>
            <td>11 p.m.</td>
            <td rowSpan="4">
              <table border="1px" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td>Xpath</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Transformation</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11 a.m.</td>
            <td>2 p.m.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2 a.m.</td>
            <td>5 a.m.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8 a.m.</td>
            <td>12 p.menter code here.</td>
            <td>XSC formatting objects</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).